# How to get valid dates from a varchar column where dates are stored in different formats

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a table in *MySql*, which contains dates as string in any format (there is not fixed pattern) it could be as `m-d-y` or `M-D-Y` or `m/d/y` or YY/MM/DD or MM/DD/YY or mm/dd/yy etc. My question is how should I detect it and then change to some particular format i.e mm/dd/yy.

Comment: U could try this query  DESCRIBE table;  and then ALTER TABLE

Comment: '01/12/13' - 13 dec 2001  OR  12 jan 2013 ?

Comment: How many different formats? Can you guess or make a list?

Comment: @Oncodeeater We know the column is string type and values are in random date formate.

Comment: @Mike Its 12 jan 2013

Comment: @1000111 six different format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guess the number of different formats you stored the dates in a varchar field then it would be easier to deal with the problem;

One way would be put all those different formats in the query given below:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m-%d-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%M-%D-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m/%d/%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m-%d-%Y'),
  ....
  .
  .

)
FROM your_table;
```

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @your_date_field := '8/8/2016';

SELECT 
COALESCE(
  STR_TO_DATE(@your_date_field,'%m-%d-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(@your_date_field,'%M-%D-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(@your_date_field,'%m/%d/%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(@your_date_field,'%M/%D/%Y')
);
```

**Output:** `2016-08-08` (`yyyy-mm-dd)`

**Note:**

But dates should be stored in a `date` datatype. Violating this will put towards this kind of cumbersome situation.

So, better move these date strings to date datatype column.

---

**More:** In order to move these date strings to a `date` datatype column you can follow the steps below:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN date_new date; 

UPDATE 
your_table
SET date_new = COALESCE(
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m-%d-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%M-%D-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m/%d/%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m-%d-%Y'),
  ....
  .
  .

);


ALTER TABLE your_table DROP COLUMN `date`;

ALTER TABLE datestable CHANGE COLUMN `date_new` `date` date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support, you have solved my challenging problem to select correct date using `COALESCE` function, I knew the `COALESCE` function but didn't came in mind. Actually some one has made the column type `varchar` and inserting/updating the date from different different places with different format, so I am correct it as by making a separate column and will store these values their with *mysql* date format and drop this column, exactly what you said is my plan to execute it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad that it's been a help.:)